# List of countries where it is possible to gain a passport entry stamp as a UK passport holder?

Tags: uk-citizens, passport-stamps

Is there an exhaustive list of countries (recognised or unrecognised by the UN, but is distinctively different in terms of passport stamp to another country or territory) where I will receive a stamp in my passport upon entry as a UK passport holder?

The excellent Wikipedia have [a list of visa requirements](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Visa_requirements_for_British_citizens) for UK passport holders which is a very helpful tool. But as a stamp collector and my obsession of British one-upmanship with my fellow travelers I am trying to find a list of guaranteed stamps for my passport. I would like to know which ones I am missing and could potentially plan future trips based on this very trivial matter.

My internet searching has proven unfruitful so far. Anyone know of any good sources or links to provide me with this information?

**EDIT:** As mentioned by Patricia in comments. Since the objective is to collect as many different passport stamps as possible, surely it would count as a different country if, and only if, it has a different stamp.

Comment: @pnuts that doesn't seem so difficult. Are there any territories where you would anticipate controversy or ambiguity?

Comment: Since the objective seems to be to collect as many different passport stamps as possible, surely it would count as a different country if, and only if, it has a different stamp.

Comment: @pnuts I'd say that any territory with an authority that stamps UK passports should be on the list. If you're bothered by the political implications you can put an asterisk by the word country as the US does in its VWP materials.

Comment: @pnuts No. Port of entry can be anything. That list would be extremely long otherwise! One per country is what I want.

Comment: @pnuts a list of sovereign states? What is a country to you? If you want to give me some guidance of the possible answers to that question that would be helpful. Otherwise I am struggling to see what the issue is with the countries aspect of the question.

Comment: @davidb For example, I got different stamps in my UK passport for mainland China and for Hong Kong. Would you count both of them?

Answer (score 1):

The passport index ranks passports by the number of countries which you can enter without a visa, it also lists the countries where you need a visa and gives the type of visa needed.

Here is a link for the UK page

https://www.passportindex.org/comparebyPassport.php?p1=uk